# Android pdf conversion

Tags: android

I am trying to input data and display it in a new activity,which done and dusted.However I want to convert my DispalyActivity to pdf format so that can be sent as a mail.
I am not able to convert it to pdf.
Plz help.Thank you!!
THis is my DispalyActivity  code..

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ITC RESOURCES..**
Button button_back;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    button_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_bck);

    //this.getActionBar().hide();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    //get the values out by key
    String name=bundle.getString("name");
    String rep=bundle.getString("rep");
    String rfq=bundle.getString("rfq");
    String vec_no=bundle.getString("ProdType");
    String vec_type=bundle.getString("Item");
    //String date=bundle.getString("date");
   // String time=bundle.getString("time");
    String facility1=bundle.getString("spinner1");
    String facility2=bundle.getString("spinner2");
    String facility3=bundle.getString("spinner3");
    String findings=bundle.getString("findings");
    String status_label=bundle.getString("status_label");
    String more_info=bundle.getString("more_info");
    String corrective_action=bundle.getString("corrective_action");

    TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET1);
    TextView rep1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET2);
    TextView rfq1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET3);
    TextView ProdType1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET4);
    TextView Item1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET5);

    TextView facility11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET8);
    TextView facility21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET9);
    TextView facility31 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET10);
    TextView findings1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET11);
    TextView status_label1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET12);
    TextView more_info1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET13);
    TextView corrective_action1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ET14);

   /* name.setText(b.getCharSequence("name"));
    rep.setText(b.getCharSequence("rep"));
    rfq.setText(b.getCharSequence("rfq"));
    vec_no.setText(b.getCharSequence("vec_no"));
    vec_type.setText(b.getCharSequence("vec_type"));
    date.setText(b.getCharSequence("date"));
    time.setText(b.getCharSequence("time"));

    facility1.setText(b.getCharSequence("facility1"));
    facility2.setText(b.getCharSequence("facility2"));
    facility3.setText(b.getCharSequence("facility3"));     

    findings.setText(b.getCharSequence("findings"));
    status_label.setText(b.getCharSequence("status_label"));
    more_info.setText(b.getCharSequence("more_info"));
    corrective_action.setText(b.getCharSequence("corrective_action"));*/

    //set the text values of the text controls
    name1.setText(name);
    rep1.setText(rep);
    rfq1.setText(rfq);
    ProdType1.setText(vec_no);
    Item1.setText(vec_type);

    facility11.setText(facility1);
    facility21.setText(facility2);
    facility31.setText(facility3);
    findings1.setText(findings);
    status_label1.setText(status_label);
    more_info1.setText(more_info);
    corrective_action1.setText(corrective_action);

        }
  public void moveTOmain(View view)
   {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
   }
```

Comment: "I am not able to convert it to pdf" -- please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: I fetched the data from sqlite..dispalyed it in a separate activity..n I wnna convert  that same activity to pdf..

Comment: I have tried taking the snapshot method,but couldn't convert that bitmap to pdf..

Comment: "but couldn't convert that bitmap to pdf" -- please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: I have tried many options ..but in vain..

Comment: Can you provide me the code please..Thank you.

Comment: "I have tried many options ..but in vain" -- then it should be very easy for you to explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: I tried taking a screenshot of the DisplayActivity..to which I succeeded,But could not make out the next part..i.e. the part of converting the bitmap image to pdf..

Comment: Lots of solutions show up when you search `android bitmap pdf` on a major search engine. Try them. If you run into problems, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: Okay fine..once I find  the code,where do I add it..in the same class or a new one?! Thank you.

Comment: I cannot really answer that. I would guess that it will wind up in a new class, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Can u send some links to me??Thank you.